# I have steel pieces after using my turbo trainer? How can I solve this problem? Is this is a problem?

Tags: trainer

I am using an Elite Directo 2019 turbo trainer. After every ride I have some pieces around my bike. How can I solve this problem? And where to search the issues? thank you for the answer. I am using a carbon framed bike.

[image]

Comment: That is a pretty close up pic, as such I can't really tell what it is of.  I can definately see the metal pixie dust you are talking about.  However, it could be coming from many places on the trainer (or the bike) so additional information would be helpful.  Where is the pixie dust under?

Welcome to Bicycles.StackExchange!

Comment: More information would definitely be useful. At the moment, it's hard to even tell what we're looking at. Is all of the reflective material on there the dust you're talking about, or is some of it just reflections off the plastic? Can you describe your setup in more detail?

Comment: Sorry for asking this but your chain does have lube on it, right? Just asking to rule out any silliness going on.

Comment: Can you grab a magnet, put it in a plastic bag, and see if the shavings are iron-based?  If yes, then they're not off your CF bike frame.

Answer (score 4):

[image]
So after Googling your model of trainer, it appears the dust is likely coming from the resistance mechanism.  With the wheel off the only bicycle components I could see generating it (and depositing it in that area) would be the chain or cassette, which seems unlikely.  There are a couple of reasons I could think of for the dust.  One could be dust that was left over from manufacturing in the trainer, vacuuming or air washing the unit could help determine if this is the case.  A second could be dust created by metal parts on the unit which are possibly breaking in and would theoretically lessen after a few rides (I'd check with the company's customer service on this front).

Personally, I'd clean the unit (with a vacuum and/or air compressor) to remove the pixie dust and if it is still appearing after two or three hours of riding I'd contact the manufacturer.  It's normal to expect some break in period for mechanical products, and an issue like this goes away after a brief period of time and the unit continues to function, it should be fine.  If not (it doesn't go away or doesn't continue to function) then the manufacture should replace it or provide a refund.

Comment: That area is directly below the cassette, however if that dust is coming off the chain or cassette something is very, very wrong, and the OP should feel high pedaling resistance.

Comment: I would go as far as saying: There almost certainly is something very wrong. Good job for locating the full picture of the trainer, but those flakes indicate that something's grinding at quite high forces that shouldn't be grinding at all. The place I see for such grinding is the contact point between frame and trainer: If any of the rotating parts comes into contact with the frame, that would explain the flakes. **And any further use would increase the damage done.** The actual source of the flakes needs to be determined **before** the grinding produces irreparable damage to the bike.

Comment: @cmaster  Fairly unlikely that the CF frame is producing metal flakes?

Comment: Looks like the contact points would be the drop outs (which are likely metal).  However, I don't see anything on the trainer side that could be causing wear there without being very obvious.

Comment: @DeletedUser Exactly. The dropouts are most likely metal. If they rub against the trainer, well, there you get flakes. We can't see exactly how the frame fits on the trainer, and we can't see how the OP's trainer differs from the image (mistake in assembly?), or how the OP attached the frame, so we have to assume the worst. And the worst is that the axle is rubbing against the metal dropouts, destroying them over time.